# How can a char variable accept Pointer(NULL) as its value?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I understand that a `char` variable can accept a `null` character(1 byte) i.e; `\0` as its value but, I don't understand how a char variable in my application below accepts a pointer(4 bytes) as its value and still works properly?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char p[10]="Its C";
    printf("%s\n",p);
    p[3]='\0';                // assigning null character 
    printf("%s\n",p);
    p[2]=NULL;               //  assigning null pointer to a char variable
    printf("%s\n",p); 
    p[1]=(void *)0;          //  assigning null pointer to a char variable
    printf("%s\n",p);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**  GCC Compiler (32 Bit Linux Platform).

Comment: Did your compiler produce any warnings for this program? If so, please edit your question to show them to us.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan Thanks for editing

Comment: @KeithThompson , That was an online editor ,which was not giving any warnings.

Comment: What online editor lets you compile code but hides warnings from you?

Comment: There is a website called indiabix.com which has a primary editor . that doesn't show any warnings.Try this link you'll find that editor http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/pointers/038002

Comment: Ick. Hiding warnings like that is pretty bad. But there is a workaround. If your program fails to compile, it will show both error messages and warnings. Temporarily add a `#error` directive, and it will show you the warnings. (But there doesn't seem to be a way to specify compiler options.) You're much better off using a compiler directly if that's at all practical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NULL` macro is required to expand to "an implementation-defined null pointer constant".

A *null pointer constant* is defined as "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`". Counterintuitively, this definition does *not* require the expansion of `NULL` to be an expression of pointer type. A common implementation is:

```
#define NULL 0
```

A null pointer constant, when used in a context that requires a pointer, may be implicitly converted to a pointer value; the result is a *null pointer*. It may also be explicitly converted using a cast, such as `(int*)NULL`.

But there's no requirement that an expression that qualifies as a null pointer constant may only be used in such a context. Which means that *if* the implementation chooses to define `NULL` as above, then this:

```
char c = NULL; // legal but ugly
```

is legal and initializes `c` to the null *character*.

Such an initialization is non-portable (since `NULL` may also expand to `((void*)0)` and misleading, so it should be avoided, but a compiler is likely to let it through without warning; `NULL` is expanded to `0` by the preprocessing phase of the compiler, and later phases see it as `char c = 0;`, which is legal and innocuous -- though personally I'd prefer `char c = '\0';`.

I just tried your example on my own 32-bit Ubuntu system, with gcc 4.7. With no options specified, the compiler warned about both `p[2]=NULL;` and `p[1]=(void *)0;`:

```
c.c:8:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
c.c:10:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

The second warning is to be expected from any C compiler; the first indicates that `NULL` is actually defined as `((void*)0)` (running the code through `gcc -E` confirms this).

The compiler *didn't* simply "accept" these assignments; it warned you about them. The C language standard merely requires a "diagnostic" for any violation of the language rules, even a syntax error; that diagnostic may legally be a non-fatal warning message.  You can make gcc behave more strictly with `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors`; replace `c89` by `c99` or `c11` to enforce rules from later versions of the standard. (EDIT: I see from comments that you're using a web interface to the compiler that hides warnings; see my comment on your question for a workaround. Warnings are important.)

If you post C code that produces compiler warnings *please* **show us the warnings** and pay close attention to them yourself. They often indicate serious problems, even illegalities, in your program.

A language-lawyer quibble: it's not even clear that this:

```
char c = (void*)0;
```

specifies a conversion from `void*` to `char`. My own view is that, since it violates a constraint, it has no defined semantics. Most compilers that don't reject it will treat it as if it were a `void*`-to-`char` conversion, and it's also been argued that this is the required behavior. But you can avoid such questions if you simply pay attention to compiler warnings and/or don't write code like that in the first place.

(The rules are a bit different for C++, but you're asking about C so I won't get into that.)

Comment: Thanks! This saves me the trouble of writing a new answer, warning of the potential for undesirable behaviour that is pointer-to-integer conversion, when NULL is defined as `((void *)0)` or some other null pointer. It might still be worth-while to quote from the standard: *Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
type.*

Comment: Thanks :) ...I would also like to read your other post in my spare time

Comment: @Keith Thompson : Thank you very much , This was the standard of explanation i was waiting for , Otherwise all of the answers given were good to go with, but this is the best.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Thanks for the extension Answer

Answer (score 2):

Because, in compilers, `NULL` is substituted for 0 in some compilers and `((void*)0)` in others.

The value `0` in itself is a valid value for `char` but with the conversion to `(void*)`, you're technically casting the 0 into a pointer type, hence why the compiler would give a warning.

Note that if the compiler substitutes `NULL` with 0, an integer constant, it'll be simply and silently converted into a `char`.

Comment: added a little explanation

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: May I know why? I anyhow edited the answer a little to make what I mean clearer.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb While adding answer as help Adel is also a learner like, fairly you should explain him your downvote  reason. that will helpful for me as well

Comment: A nearly meaningless quibble: `NULL` may expand to `((void*)0)`, but not to `(void*)0`; the parentheses are required (see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.2p5)). There's an argument that `((void*)0)` is not valid, since 6.5.1p7 doesn't actually *say* that a parenthesized null pointer constant is a null pointer constant, but I'm sure the intent is to permit it.

Comment: @AdelQodmani: I suggest cleaning up that first sentence. It still suggests that `((void*)0)` is a perfectly valid value for type `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I edited the answer, is it clearer/more correct now?

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is a macro and for almost platform  is defined in this way

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
```

(from `stddef.h` from my Ubuntu)

and when you write

```
p[2]=NULL;
```

It's the same

```
p[2]=(void *)0; //for c
p[2]=0; //for c++
```

It's the same

```
p[2] = 0; // the 0 is casted to char 0 for C --> '\0'
```

Comment: I noticed  question is taged only `c` so you answer should get a + :) :) and + to show difference in c and c++ good

Answer (score 2):

On your platform, a pointer is generally a numerical value treated as a memory address. Since the `char` type is numeric, a null pointer (memory address `0x00`) is being stored in `p[1]`

The 32-bit value of the pointer (in this case, `0x00000000`) is truncated to 8-bit `char` length: `0x00`.

Comment: No, pointers are not simply numerical values; as far as the language is concerned, they're quite distinct entities. If `NULL` expands to `((void*)0)`, the assignment is a constraint violation, requiring at least a warning (there's no implicit conversion from `void*` to `char`). If `NULL` expands to `0`, there is no pointer conversion; `NULL` expands to a constant expression of type `int`, which is implicitly converted to `char`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - OP explicitly stated he was using GCC on a 32-bit Linux platform. On this platform, pointers *are* numeric memory addresses. Don't believe me? Do a memory dump :)

Comment: Given the added "On your platform" qualification, it's a bit better. But there is no conversion from `void*` to `intptr_t`, since there's no mention of `inptr_t`, either explicit or implicit, in the code. Assigning a `void*` value to a `char` is a constraint violation; assuming the compiler merely warns about it, it will *probably* result in a conversion (*not* a cast, which is an explicit operator) from `void*` to `char`. In any case, IMHO it's better to think of pointers as being distinct from integers; the way they're represented internally is an implementation detail.

Comment: The semantics of a conversion from `void*` to `char` (or generally from any pointer type to any integer type) are implementation-defined, but "are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment". But the most important thing to know about the code is that it's invalid.

Comment: Are you sure that's the definition of `NULL` *in C++*? In C++, that's not a valid null pointer constant (it's valid in C). On my system, `g++` 4.7.2 expands `NULL` to `__null`. And `char c = NULL;` is "valid" only in the sense that a compiler *might* permit it; it's non-portable and poor style in both C and C++.

Comment: @KeithThompson - On my system, `g++ 4.7.2` expands `NULL` to either `__null` or `0`, depending on the preprocessor selected. As for NULL-assigning being non-portable, which compilers do not permit it? GCC likes it fine: http://ideone.com/lLEaNe

Comment: That code produces a warning when compiled with either `gcc` or `g++`. Does ideone.com hide warnings? And gcc isn't the only compiler in existence; a fully conforming C compiler could have `#define NULL (void*)0` and treat an attempt to assign that to a `char` object as a fatal error. Do you dispute my assertion that it's poor style? `NULL` is intended for use in pointer contexts; assigning it to a `char` object is *at least* potentially confusing. Is there some reason you'd *want* to assign `NULL` to a `char` object?

Comment: @KeithThompson - It doesn't hide any warnings as far as I know. And I've seen NULL assigned to `char` arrays `char s[10] = NULL;` as a terminator, I only used a single non-array variable for simplicity. However, at this point, I think we're getting beyond the question, which can essentially be phrased as "what is happening here?", and which I believe I have already answered.

Comment: I've seen it too. It's a common and understandable mistake, but definitely a mistake; that's not how `NULL` is meant to be used, any more than `double x = NULL;`. The null *character* is spelled `'\0'`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I'm aware of that. However since on most (all?) modern systems, `NULL` is numerically equivalent to zero, the mistake is rarely noticed. Let's hope future systems stick with zero-NULLs :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile this with `-Wall` option and you will see that there are impilicit convertions taking place.

Comment: Compiling *without* `-Wall` produces warnings.